# Creating file multi-lined files through batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch code that would set a variable and create a txt or bat file with that variable as the body. The thing is I want the variable to be set to
maybe 40 lines of code that would be formatted correctly so it would run smoothly. Example:

```
set /a content=

@echo off

echo insert

echo code

echo here

cls


echo %content% >hi.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 set /a content=
 @echo off
 echo insert
 echo code
 echo here
 cls
 echo %content% >hi.bat
```

It's probably better to do this

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set NL=^


echo echo/insert!NL!echo/code
set content=echo/insert!NL!echo/code
set content=!content!!NL!!echo/here!!NL!pause
ECHO !content! > hi.bat
```

This should work! It just creates a new line between each variable.

Comment: OK, but how would I do this for a lot more code? There's no way to put the whole code in brackets or something? It seems really tedious.

Comment: Not sure, but it is a pain to do that, though if you tried it may get there ;9 there probably is a way though...

Comment: Sure, I have like a whole code I want in there. How should I get it to you?

Comment: You have to use @nephi12 tag to reply to him.  Only the question writer and answer writer get the answers automatically without an @

Answer (score 0):

If you use this style then you need to escape characters like: ) and & and < > | and ^ with `^` and double % to %%

```
@echo off
(
echo.echo insert
echo.echo code
echo.echo here
echo.echo cls
) > hi.bat
```